# Pycharm numpy module has no attribute 'py'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pycharm

Just getting into programming by going through a load of beginner projects. I started one to plot sine and cosine curves, and the code they gave was:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.arange(0, 4*np.py, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Every time I try and run the code, it gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Alex/PycharmProjects/projects2/sin2.py", line 5, in <module>
    x = np.arange(0, 4*np.py, 0.1)
  File "C:\Users\Alex\anaconda3\envs\projects2\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 220, in __getattr__
    "{!r}".format(__name__, attr))
AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'py'
```

I've reinstalled Python, pycharm, and numpy to no avail. I believe I'm properly using the anaconda interpreter and I see numpy is properly installed on it. I'm not sure what else I should try, so any suggestions would help. Maybe I should try another IDE? I do like Pycharm so far but I have seen other people with similar issues using Pycharm, so any suggestions there would also be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to get np.pi
The constant 3.1415926535897932384626433...

If you change it in your code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


x = np.arange(0, 4 * np.pi, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

It properly runs

Comment: That did it! I must have copied the code over wrong and missed it (saying pi in my head and typing it as py) Now I get a cool graph :)

Comment: Yeah... that happens sometimes :p

Answer (score 0):

I not very familiar with numpy, but I looked through the docs and couldn't find anything for py being part of numpy. Maybe I didn't look hard enough, but it could have been replaced with an update? Also, you could try changing it to "np.py()" with parentheses because it could just be a function instead (however that is probably not likely assuming you got this from a prebuilt project).

Comment: This looks like more a comment than an answer.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know, why are you using **4*np.py**, I have seen the documentation of NumPy and it has no such attribute as py. You can try following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
y = np.sin(x)

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.title('sine wave')      # To give a title
plt.xlabel('Time')          # To give a x-label
plt.ylabel('Y-values')      # To give a y-label
plt.grid(True, which='both')  # Turns Grid to True
plt.axhline(y=0, color='k')   # Draw a black horizontal line at y=0
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: sine wave]